# Options Theme - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, frameworks, themes, options-menu

Searching about options page, I found a lot of themes that uses a options theme page like this one:

[image]

There is an pre-built option? What framework do you advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not a fan of plugins go with these two options, where you can place the files within your theme and a options panel will appear. I have listed two very good ones that alot of developer use. Also there are many open source option frameworks but they're not as documented.

1. [Option Theme Framework](http://wptheming.com/options-framework-theme/)
2. [Propanel](http://codecanyon.net/item/propanel-wordpress-theme-options-panel/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Options Tree plugin for this.

http://www.wordpress.org/extend/plugins/option-tree/

It's very good, easy to customise via an XML file that you load in and also easy to style the panel so your client feels like they've got a fully customised options panel put together just for them.

There is also a media uploader built in, very handy for a gallery tab.

Comment: And while this is a plugin it can be integrated into a theme so the plugin does not have to be downloaded. Option Tree is a great option framework to use, easy to work with and very well documented.

Comment: Very good point @WH Web Dev. I've seen it bundled in commercial themes ( Super Skeleton for one).

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is that I've seen it bundled in commercial themes in this way - in the theme directory rather than in plugins.

Answer (score 0):

NHP is a powerful one, but it just merged with ReduxFramework to make it even more powerful. Give it a go.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/redux-framework/

Comment: Did I mention Redux runs as a plugin or embedded?